# Do one-way functions have to be polynomial in input bit length, or is the relative difficulty of an inverse more important?

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography

Wikipedia defines it as being a polynomial function, but I'm looking for a clarification.

Specifically, there was a candidate for a OWF I was thinking about, but it relies heavily on taking the greatest prime factor of numbers around size $2^n$, if $n$ is the number of bits in an input bitstring. Since factorization is not a polynomial-time operation, I would *guess* this is disqualifying.

However, it seems likely that it would still be one-way in the sense that any inverse algorithm would generally have no other choice but to brute-force it, meaning it would ostensibly take $2^t$ time to "undo", if it takes $t$ time to run once. So, relatively speaking, it would arguably accomplish the goal of a one-way function, and thus my question.

Comment: The bottom line is that "doing" it needs to be practical/feasible, and "undoing" it should be infeasible. No point of having an algorithm that formally satisfies some definition, if it cannot be applied anywhere. For ordinary applications, the input string is expected to be of size large enough for a symmetrical key (e.g. AES-256) to fit in or be agreed, so if your algorithm cannot handle $n\ge 256$ it is likely that it won't have practical use. (It may make for interesting math, though!)

Comment: Thanks for the point about 256 as a good benchmark. But also, I'm interested from a theoretical standpoint even if the algorithm is unfeasible, since proving it would imply P$\not =$NP, so I'm curious whether that result might still hold even though the algorithm isn't P... except it is in a relative sense, and I'm wondering if that's enough.

Comment: Yeah, OWFs need to run in time polynomial in the input length. So if it takes a $n$-bit input and then internally expands it to a $2^n$-bit intermediate value it wouldn't qualify as an OWF.